# Как с помощью регулярного выражения получить первое число не начинающиеся на определенные цифры?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, google-spreadsheet

Как получить первое попавшиеся число не начинающиеся с `2000000` ?

Дано

```
2000000116112, 20000004872, 6934177705021, 98343434, 234222, 2000002343574
```

Нужно получить

```
6934177705021
```

Это нужно для гугл таблицы для функции REGEXEXTRACT

Ребята из чата https://t.me/contributor_pw_chat подсказали ответ.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

```
REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(O4:O; "(?:^|, )20000\d*";); "\d+")
```

Comment: А какие ваши попытки решения задачи?

Comment: сначала была задача получить первое число, использовал такое выражение "^[^,]*". Но потом шаблон изменился и стало нужно пропускать числа с определенным паттерном. Вот и спрашиваю. Все попытки мои закончились неудачей.

Comment: Почему именно REGEXEXTRACT? значение можн выдернуть и другими функциями

Answer (score 3):

```
(\b(?!2000000)\d+\b)
```

`\b` - граница слова
`(?!2000000)` - негативный просмотре вперед
`\d+` - один и более символов цифр
`\b` - граница слова

Пример: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EAlScV/1)

А далее уже из полученного результата получить первое значение

---

После выяснения что автор вопроса использует гугл таблицы, которые не поддерживают негативный просмотр вперед(и многое другое) , предлагаю использовать следующее решение

По пути: *Инструменты* -> *редактор скриптов*
Создаем функцию:

```
function regexmatcher(s) {
  var REGEX = /(\b(?!2000000)\d+\b)/g;
 return s.match(REGEX)[0];
}
```

В которой используем регулярное выражение из исходного ответа.
Далее на листе вызываем функцию:

```
=regexmatcher(адрес ячейки с данными)
```

Для примера:
[image: Пример работы]

Comment: Спасибо. Не догоняю все равно) https://regex101.com/r/VCXnlO/1 - показывает последнее число, а так (\b(?!2000)\d+\b), - показывает следующие, но захватывает запятую. Как от запятой избавиться?

Comment: @content `(\b(?!2000000)\d+(?=,))` если нужно что бы после захвата цифр шла запятая, то используйте позитивный просмотр вперед. Но это не правильное решение, а что если с 2000000 будут начинаться первые два числа, то последнее не будет захвачено, так как не будет запятой вконце. Правильнее записать массив полученный при помощи регулярного выражения в ответе и из массива достать 1 значение. Какой язык вы используете? Или это для какого-то онлайн сервиса?

Comment: это для уггл таблицы. Не знаю какой это язык) Для функции REGEXEXTRACT.

Comment: синтаксис re2 используется в гугл таблицах https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt

Comment: @content дополнил ответ, по другому честно говоря не знаю как сделать

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```go
REGEXEXTRACT(O4:O; "(?:^|,\s)((?:[013-9]\d{4}|\d[1-9]\d{3}|\d{2}[1-9]\d{2}|\d{3}[1-9]\d|\d{4}[1-9])\d*)")
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/H2UI0M/1/).

*Подробности*

- `(?:^|,\s)` - незахватывающая подмаска (используется только для группировки шаблонов): или начало строки, или запятая и пробел после неё
- `((?:[013-9]\d{4}|\d[1-9]\d{3}|\d{2}[1-9]\d{2}|\d{3}[1-9]\d|\d{4}[1-9])\d*)` - Захватывающая подмаска (находит возвращаемый текст):

  - `(?:[013-9]\d{4}|\d[1-9]\d{3}|\d{2}[1-9]\d{2}|\d{3}[1-9]\d|\d{4}[1-9])` - (незахватывающая подмаска) несколько шаблонов, которые по очереди исключают каждую последующую цифру в числе `20000` (5 цифр, 5 альтернатив):

    - `[013-9]\d{4}|` - цифра, отличная от нуля, и затем четыре цифры
    - `\d[1-9]\d{3}|` - цифра, затем цифра, отличная от нуля, и затем три цифры или
    - `\d{2}[1-9]\d{2}|` - две цифры, цифра, отличная от нуля, и две цифры
    - `\d{3}[1-9]\d|` - три цифры, затем цифра, отличная от нуля, затем одна цифра или
    - `\d{4}[1-9]` - четыре цифры и затем цифра, отличная от нуля
  - `\d*` - ноль  и более цифр.